# Simple query to get group results

Tags: c#, sql

How can I get only unique departments from the below example?

```
Dept Id                                       Created Date 
06013cd7-2224-4220-b048-a54bbd1ff403          2009-09-08 17:36:11.293
06013cd7-2224-4220-b048-a54bbd1ff403          2009-09-08 17:41:54.857
5e29bd98-04ba-452d-bfcd-caa63ab9018b          2009-09-08 17:20:45.373
```

I tried like this

```
select top 10 deptid, 
    (Select convert(varchar,createddate,101)) 
from depts 
where [status]='Y' 
group by deptid,convert(varchar,createddate,101)
```

but is showing all results. I want this:

```
Dept Id                                       Created Date 
06013cd7-2224-4220-b048-a54bbd1ff403          2009-09-08 
5e29bd98-04ba-452d-bfcd-caa63ab9018b          2009-09-08
```

Can you help me to write this query

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT deptid, MAX(createdate) FROM depts WHERE [status] = 'Y' GROUP BY deptid
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning all rows because you're including the date in the grouping. Try:

```
select deptid, Max(convert(varchar,createddate,101)) AS MaxDate
from depts 
where [status]='Y' 
group by deptid
```